# Downloading zip file from url using wget or curl

Tags: unix, curl, wget

I'm facing difficulty downloading the zip file from url by using wget or curl.

wget -O 'https://msi.example.com/admin/ui/feedbackCSV/Reports/6945u499dcf9e00010ae618?reports%5B%5D=pageviews&%20reports%5B%5D=searches&from=Nov%2012%202020&to=Nov%2019%202020' /home/user/path/

curl 'https://msi.example.com/admin/ui/feedbackCSV/Reports/6945u499dcf9e00010ae618?reports%5B%5D=pageviews&%20reports%5B%5D=searches&from=Nov%2012%202020&to=Nov%2019%202020'  --output /home/user/path/

I tried with wget and curl but neither worked for me, when I manually paste the above URL in my browser I am able to download the correct zip file when I am trying to do this with curl or wget I'm getting the zip file with a single  HTML file in it, not the files that I expected

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you make any effort to investigate this problem yourself? What did this HTML file say? Have you tried examining the response headers from the remote server?

Comment: Is there a redirect or something that should be folowed to get to the actual file?

Comment: @r3mainer, it's returning the login page HTML of the site. I've passed my credentials along with the request still getting log_in page HTML

Comment: @Rahul That information belongs in the question, not in the comments. My advice would be to use your browser's developer tools to examine the zip file HTTP request in detail, and make sure you replicate it exactly (including request headers such as `Referer` and `User-Agent`)